# 5006 : Unable to redirect to Vendors web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL. - PHP Inframe integration

Tags: opayo

Hoping someone can help me.

I'm working on the Server Inframe integration and I can get the iframe to load with the inputs for the card details, but when you click to continue i get the following error:

`5006 : Unable to redirect to Vendors web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL.`

My notification URL is:

`https://" . $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST] . "/index.php?route=payment/sagepay_inframe/notificationURL`

and in that function I have

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo 'Status=OK' . chr(13) . chr(10) . 'RedirectURL=https://example/url' . chr(13) . chr(10);
```

I've tried using ngrok to make my localhost accessible but nothing seems to work. Can anyone advise if I'm doing this correctly or if I'm missing something? Really pulling my hair out with this one. 
Thanks.

Comment: Your notification endpoint may exist, and may work (to a fashion - you need to check and record the results) - but you still need to tell Sage Pay what that URL is. How are you doing that? You have not provided those details, but this is likely where it is going wrong..

Answer (score -1):

The callback process won't work on localhost. Your NotificationURL (that you supply in the registration post) must be accessible to the internet.....