# RedirectURL error 5006 on server iframe intergration

Tags: php, opayo

We have implemented the server type integration with the low profile iframe in place. We have provided all of the mandatory parameters that are posted to sagepay, and with the response received we create the iframe url and display the card input fields. Once a user enters the card information, they are presented with the 5006 number. The documentation is very unclear on how and when the redirect URL should be provided to sagepay. Does anyone have any sample code to show us how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not providing the redirectURL as a parameter.

See here:-
[5006 : Unable to redirect to Vendors web site. The Vendor failed to provide a RedirectionURL. - PHP Inframe integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53523832/5006-unable-to-redirect-to-vendors-web-site-the-vendor-failed-to-provide-a-re)